# Render object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I want to render Object "genres" but my console returns to me :

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {genre}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

My code

```
function Movie({title,summary,year,poster,genres}){ 
    return(
        <div className="movie">
            {genres.map(genre=>{return {genre}})} //doesn't work
        {genres.map(genre=>{return <li>{genre}</li>})}
         </div>
    )
}
```

the first code

```
{genres.map(genre=>{returns {genre}})}
```

doesn't work

But the second code below works well.

```
{genres.map(genre=>{returns <li>{genre}</li>})}
```

What's the difference between these two things?

Comment: This article explains it in details 
https://www.akashmittal.com/react-error-objects-not-valid-react-child/

Comment: First one is returning an array of objects (`{ genre }` creates an object using [shorthand property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)) . The second one is returning an array of `<li>`

Comment: `<div className="movie">{ genres.join(" ") }</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
{genres.map(genre=>{returns {genre}})}
```

returns an **object**, out of each item in the array: `{ genre: 'drama' }`

However, this other line

```
{genres.map(genre=>{returns <li>{genre}</li>})}
```

The `{` inside the JSX for `li` won't turn it into an Object, but will access its value: `<li>drama</li>`

Answer (score 0):

The first code returns an object with key "genre" which its value is the genere value, and react can't render it.

The second one return the value of genre, because the braces here aren't an object braces but the correct syntax of putting variables inside html in react.

If you want to return the value without li, do: `{genres.map(genre=> genre)}`

Comment: This expression returns array of undefineds though. 
genres.map(genre=>{return {genre}})

Comment: It was really helpful for me.Thanks a lot